# "Cannot add foreign key constraint" error in MySQL 5.6.16 in very simple case of two tables: Why?

Tags: mysql, sql, windows, foreign-keys

Here is the exact SQL I attempt to execute (using SQLYog as a MySQL client on Windows):

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `test`;
CREATE TABLE `test` (
  `id` INT (11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE = INNODB ;

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `temp`;
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE `temp` (
  dish_id INT (11) NOT NULL,
  user_id INT (11) NOT NULL,
  UNIQUE KEY (dish_id, user_id),
  FOREIGN KEY `test` (dish_id) REFERENCES test (id)
) ENGINE = INNODB ;
```

Here is the exact error received upon the attempt to create `temp`:

```
Error Code: 1215
Cannot add foreign key constraint
```

It looks to me like everything is in order - the data type and signed-ness of the two related keys is the same; the names appear to be kosher; what is going on?

What am I doing wrong?  Why is the foreign key constraint failing to be created?

Comment: Do you mean: `FOREIGN KEY \`temp\` (dish_id) REFERENCES test (id)` ?

Comment: @Raptor That shouldn't make a difference, since it's just the name of the FK relationship, but I'll try it...

Comment: @Raptor ... and I receive the same error (after making the change you suggested).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's because you're trying to add a foreign key constraint to a temporary table.

From the manual:

> Foreign key relationships involve a parent table that holds the
>   central data values, and a child table with identical values pointing
>   back to its parent. The FOREIGN KEY clause is specified in the child
>   table. The parent and child tables must use the same storage engine.
>   They must not be TEMPORARY tables.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html

EDIT:
Try it with a permanent table.  It works.

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `test`;
CREATE TABLE `test` (
  `id` INT (11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE = INNODB ;

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `temp`;
CREATE TABLE `temp` (
  dish_id INT (11) NOT NULL,
  user_id INT (11) NOT NULL,
  UNIQUE KEY (dish_id, user_id),
  FOREIGN KEY `test` (dish_id) REFERENCES test (id)
) ENGINE = INNODB ;
```

Comment: Do you know what version of MySQL this was introduced in?  The code I've copied comes from a known-working web application (which is using MySQL 5.1.63).

Comment: It is in the docs all the way back to 5.0: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html

Comment: I should add that, as far as I remember, InnoDB and foreign key support was also added in 5.0.  So it looks like you could never add foreign key constraints to temporary tables in MySql.